# NullPointerExceptionException; "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, nullpointerexception

I always get this error in the console when I'm running my program:

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 74, Size: 74
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Graph.paint(Graph.java:47)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The program works like it should do, showing some graphs in a coordinate system but I want to know why this messages shows up and fix it.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;   

import javax.swing.*; 
public class Graph extends Panel {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Graph Heretsu = new Graph();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize (820, 820);
    f.add (Heretsu);
    f.setVisible(true);


  }                          

public void paint (Graphics g) {

    g.setColor (Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine (5, 5, 5, 600);
    g.drawLine (5, 600, 600, 600);

    for (int i = 20; i < 600; i += 20) {
      g.drawLine (i, 598, i, 602);
      g.drawLine (3, i, 7, i);
    }
    g.drawLine (605, 600, 595, 595);
    g.drawLine (605, 600, 595, 605);
    g.drawLine (5, 0,0, 5);
    g.drawLine (5, 0, 10, 5);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 15));
    g.setColor (Color.BLACK);;
    g.drawString ("Heretsu Enterprises",650, 50);

    Untersuchung untersuchung = new Untersuchung();
    Auslesen.lesen();
    ArrayList messwerte = new ArrayList();
    messwerte = untersuchung.getMesswerte();

    System.out.println(messwerte.size());
    for (int i = 1; i < messwerte.size(); i ++ ) {
      g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
      g.drawLine((i*7),((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getPuls(),(i+1)*7, ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i+1)).getPuls());  
      g.drawLine((i*7),((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getDiastole(),(i+1)*7, ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i+1)).getDiastole()); 
      g.drawLine((i*7),((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getSystole(),(i+1)*7, ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i+1)).getSystole());     
    }

  }     
}
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, the problem is in line 47 of your Graph class. What's on that line?

Comment: Do you *really* have a `NullPointerException` *and* an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? It seems very odd to have two reported exceptions in the same line of the log...

Comment: @Baran Where did you see "NullPointerException"?

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < messwerte.size(); i ++ ) {
      g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
      g.drawLine((i*7),((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getPuls(),(i+1)*7, ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i+1)).getPuls());
```

What will the value of i be the last time through the loop? What will happen when you add 1 to it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me why you'd get a `NullPointerException` wrapping the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but this is the problem:

```
for (int i = 1; i < messwerte.size(); i ++ ) {
  g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
  g.drawLine((i*7),((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getPuls(),(i+1)*7, ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i+1)).getPuls());
```

Note the call here:

```
messwerte.get(i+1)
```

When `i` is equal to `messwerte.size() - 1`, then `i + 1` will be equal to  `messwerte.size()`, so it's out of the bounds of the list.

I *suspect* you want to either use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < messwerte.size() - 1; i++) {
```

... or use the original bounds, but use indexes of `i - 1` and `i` instead of `i` and `i + 1`.

Comment: Hey, I tried this and now I just get following error: java.lang.NullPointerException74 Dont know what the 74 means :/

Comment: I have 4 more codes, you want me to post all of them?

Comment: No, I'd recommend trying to reduce the code to a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. And really, it looks like we've solved your immediate issue (the index out of bounds exception) - it sounds like you should probably ask a separate question for why you're getting more output.